# Why doesn't the Kernel Density Estimate function appear in AniMove plugin?

Tags: qgis, kernel-density

can anyone tell me why the Kernel Density Estimate function does not appear under my AniMove plugin in QGIS? I can only perform the MCP. I run Windows OS.

Comment: the last time i tried the AniMove plugin nearly all of the functions didn't work anymore. Most likely because the plugin hasn't been updated since a while...

Answer (score 2):

You need the scipy file in the PythonFolder to run the Kernel Density Estimation UD.
You can download the scipy setup from "http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/scipy/scipy/0.12.0/scipy-0.12.0-win32-superpack-python2.7.exe"
After running the set up save it in the Python Folder in your QGIS. 
Restart QGIS and check. 
You will have the Kernel Density Estimate with MCP

Comment: As the above question is more than four years old: is it still necessary to have the scipy file installed in order to execute a Kernel? The Kernel function does not appear under the Animove plugin but I'm not sure that the Scipy file is the reason. If so, can someone explain how one can save it in the Python folder?